# LUA HMAC Generation issue in 5.1 version

Tags: lua, kong, kong-plugin

I have an issue while I am creating the HMAC in LUA 5.1 version and same code is working in node.js

Node.js Code :

```
crypto.createHmac(
  CONSTANTS.HMAC_ALORITHM_SHA,
  Buffer.from(
    secretAccessKey,
    CONSTANTS.BASE64_ENCODING
  )
).update(
  Buffer.from(
    stringToSign, 
    CONSTANTS.UTF8
  )
).digest(
  CONSTANTS.BASE64_ENCODING
);
```

I wanted to write in the same code  LUa 5.1.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
local sha2 = require("sha2")
local your_hmac_as_hex_string = sha2.hmac(
   sha2.sha1,  -- SHA-1
   "secretAccessKey as binary string", 
   "stringToSign"
)
local your_hmac_as_binary_string = sha2.hex2bin(your_hmac_as_hex_string)
```

The library is [here](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/pure_lua_SHA2)

---

**UPDATE:**

If your key is stored as base64, you need to convert it from base64 to binary:

```
local binary_key = sha2.base642bin(base64_key)
-- invoke sha2.hmac() here
```

And if you want to convert the result to base64:

```
local your_hmac_as_base64 = sha2.bin2base64(your_hmac_as_binary_string)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and I can hope it will work with sha256 . Will try and update .

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response . unfortunately I am not getting  same hash string what I am getting from node.js code .i have tried every-thigh below is node js code .. 1. let accesskey = Buffer.from('AWS KEY', 'base64') o/p - <Buffer 26 e 4a 4a df> 2. let hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256",accesskey) 3.let signString = Buffer.from(signString "utf-8");  let hmacUpdate  = hmac.update(signString); hmacUpdateBase64 = hmacUpdate.digest("base64"); //final Hmac    local LUA code your_hmac_as_hex_string = sha2.hmac(
   sha2.sha256,  -- SHA-1
   secretKeyBinary,
   signString
)

Comment: @AshishMishra - Answer updated, module `sha2.lua` is also updated on GitHub.

Comment: If it still doesn't work please show exact input arguments of your Lua script (and exact result string you're expecting)

Comment: Sure @EgorSkriptunoff . I will try and update you .Thanks once again

Comment: Thanks @EgorSkriptunoff .. its helps me a lot . now working